# imagemagick cannot read these files

Tags: php, image, imagemagick, jpeg, decode

I have jasper installed and the lastest version of imagemagick. When I attempt to process these two files: [here](http://www.posters.ws/images/340370/godfather.jpg) and [here](http://www.nullamatix.com/images/I-dunno-lol.jpg)

I get a decode error. Can anyone let me know which other packages I need to install for imagemagick to read these files properly?

Comment: What do you mean by "process"? I have no  problems with godfather.jpg...

Comment: When I run Identify I get a decode error.

Answer (score 1):

Has your IM been compiled with `--with-jpeg=no` or `--without-jpeg`?

Or did the compilation fail to include JPEG support because of a lack of decoder libraries being installed?  You need `libjpeg` installed, and the development header files for that library.

You can find out what formats are supported by issuing the command:

```
$ identify -list format
```

If you state your OS (inc. distribution if Linux) and how you installed IM, you might get more information on how to resolve it.  If you are on linux the package names are probably `libjpeg` and `libjpeg-devel`.